# Auto switching between UITextFields with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have 4 `UITextFields` in one `UIView` like this:

[image]

each `UITextField` limited to 4 characters. i want implement a auto switching between `UITextFields` with count characters of each `UITextField`.

i use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` for limitation characters:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let maxLength = 4
        var newString = String()
        let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
        newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        return newString.length <= maxLength
    }
```

and this is my switching implement:

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField){

    let text = textField.text

    if text?.utf16.count == 4 {
        switch textField {
        case firstPartTextField:
            secondPartTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        case secondPartTextField:
            thirdPartTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        case thirdPartTextField:
            fourthPartTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is switch to previous `UITextField` in deleting texts, i can not detect backSpace event when `UITextField` is empty.

Comment: (1) [Not all credit cards are 16-digit long](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19161529/224671) (2) Maybe you could use [existing](https://github.com/3lvis/FormTextField) [libraries](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentCardTextField.html) instead of inventing your own.

Comment: Try this answer, this worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39483754/6245319

Comment: i personally don't like to input a number into 4 seperate textfields :(

Comment: for example pasting creditcard from my 1Password is not possible with this 4 Textfields :(

Answer (score 1):

**Add target for textField in viewDidLoad()**

```
firstTxt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    secTxt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    thirdTxt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    fourTXt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

**Than create selector method**

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

```
    let text = textField.text

    if text?.utf16.count == 1{
        switch textField{
        case firstTxt:
            secTxt.becomeFirstResponder()
        case secTxt:
            thirdTxt.becomeFirstResponder()
        case thirdTxt:
            fourTXt.becomeFirstResponder()
        case fourTXt:
            fourTXt.resignFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: As above each UITextField had a selector which call by self and when the text will change it will count the character and when it comes true to the condition it will change to next UITextField

Answer (score 0):

Make an outlet collection of all your textfields and configure them like so:

OutletCollection:

```
@IBOutlet var textfields: [UITextField]!
```

Add this in viewDidLoad:

```
for (i, tf) in textfields.enumerated() {
    tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    tf.clipsToBounds = true
    tf.tag = i
    tf.delegate = self
}
```

In the target function, you'll restrict the count in this manner:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
       let text = textField.text!
       if text.utf16.count >= 4 {
           if textField.tag < 4 {
               codeTextfields[textField.tag + 1].becomeFirstResponder()
           }
           else {
               textField.resignFirstResponder()
           }
       }
}
```

This will the change in one of your delegate methods:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = ""
}
```

Refined version of the following answer: [How to move cursor from one text field to another automatically in swift ios programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331839/how-to-move-cursor-from-one-text-field-to-another-automatically-in-swift-ios-pro)