# Secure TextField clears whole text, on clearing single character using backspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've used two secure textfields(new password & confirm password), When I tried to clear a single character in a textField using backspace. It clears the whole text. How to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect `backspace` tapped and then remove last element from string with using `textField` delegate

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
let  char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

if (isBackSpace == -92) {
     print("Backspace pressed")
}
return true
}
```

> Dont forget to add UITextFieldDelegate to your ViewController

Comment: let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\b") -> Invalid escape sequence in literal

Comment: try "\\b", this should get rid of that error

Comment: Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: I can but my english might not be enough to explain it :). This is the good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/51577826/9110909 @VikramanR