# textField Maximum length and Postal Code validation

Tags: swift, validation, uitextfield, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a textField to input a Canadian postal code. And I am using the following code to ensure the formatting is correct or else show an alert saying the formatting is incorrect. This is working with no problem on `saveBtnClick`; but I cant type in the field as it continues returning `false` into the textField because of the `validZipCode` function.I also need make sure the maximum length of characters for this field does not exceed 7 characters so the user cant type more than seven characters. I see many solutions only for setting the maximum length; but cant figure out how to do this with an existing condition that I mentioned here for postal code validation. Here is my current code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var postalCodeTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    phoneNumberTextField.delegate = self
    postalCodeTextField.delegate = self
}

func validZipCode(postalCode:String)->String{
    let postalcodeRegex = "^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][- ]*[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]$"
    let pinPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", postalcodeRegex)
    let bool = pinPredicate.evaluate(with: postalCode) as Bool
  return bool.description
}

@IBAction func saveBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let isPostalCodeValid = validZipCode(postalCode: postalCodeTextField.text ?? "")

    if isPostalCodeValid == "false" {

        simpleAlert(title: "Error!", msg: "Please enter a valid CA postal code")

    } else
        if isPostalCodeValid == "true" {
       //the postalCaode is correct formatting
    }

}




func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
        let newString = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if textField == phoneNumberTextField {
        textField.text = formattedNumber(number: newString)
    } else

        if textField == postalCodeTextField {
            textField.text = validZipCode(postalCode: newString)
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `validZipCode` would always return `false` if we pass single character to it.  So ,validate the predicate on click of `saveButton`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var postalCodeTextField: UITextField!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
            postalCodeTextField.delegate = self
        }

        func validZipCode(postalCode:String)->Bool{
              let postalcodeRegex = "^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][- ]*[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]$"
            let pinPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", postalcodeRegex)
            let bool = pinPredicate.evaluate(with: postalCode) as Bool
            return bool
        }

        @IBAction func saveBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

            let isPostalCodeValid = validZipCode(postalCode: postalCodeTextField.text ?? "")

            if isPostalCodeValid == false {
                print("false")
               // simpleAlert(title: "Error!", msg: "Please enter a valid CA postal code")

            } else
                if isPostalCodeValid == true {
                    print("true")
               //the postalCaode is correct formatting
            }

        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
             guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

            if textField == postalCodeTextField {
                // add their new text to the existing text
                let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

                // make sure the result is under 7 characters
                return updatedText.count <= 7
            }else{
                return true
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: This is Great. Thank you! Do you how I can also have the postal code include a space after the 3th character? so when you type in there the result would look like `XXX XXX` Which is 7 in total and the fourth is always a space

Comment: You can modify the delegate methods as,

    if textField == postalCodeTextField {
                // add their new text to the existing text
                let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
                
                if(currentText.count == 3){
                    postalCodeTextField.text = postalCodeTextField.text! + " "
                }
    
                // make sure the result is under 7 characters
                return updatedText.count <= 7
            }

Comment: I actually did that; but the problem is when I tried to backspace and delete; once it gets to character 3 it doesnt let the user to delete any further since the character.count goes from 4 to 3 - and here were are saying at 3 characters put a space which makes it abck to 4 characters

Comment: Ok so I used this solution to detect if we are backspacing and in that case I dont input space. otherwise I put space : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504304/detect-backspace-event-in-uitextfield