# Detect Backspace in SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've seen other questions on how to detect a backspace in an empty UITextField (UIKit).  However, is there an easy way to do this with SwiftUI or using Introspect?  Doing it with a textfield which is populated is quite simple, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it with an empty textfield.

Thank you!

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504304/detect-backspace-event-in-uitextfield

Comment: Thank you, but this is for UIKit, not SwiftUI.  I know it's possible there, but I was curious about in pure SwiftUI.

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you would want to detect backspaces since there is a binding already and a place holder text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been a long time coming, but I have come up with an idea.
(Not that I have thoroughly tested it).
It is Hack-like.

The idea is to add Zero-Width Space (ZWSP) to the first character.
By always adding ZWSP, even if the character appears to be zero, onChange/onReceive will occur because the ZWSP is actually present.

```
TextField("placeholder", text: $inputText)
  .onReceive(Just(inputText)) { text in
    if !text.hasPrefix("\u{200B}") {
      inputText = "\u{200B}" + text
    }
    // other code
  }
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution.  I had to work quite hard at it to cover many scenarios in my use case but ultimately I achieved exactly what I wanted using this.  And doesn't feel too much like a hack.  Of course would be nice if they just add the detect delete functionality.

Comment: this won't work always. It works 90% times. But when i keep on testing ,it fails 10% times

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll just put this as an answer instead. Even though it's for UIKit you can still wrap it in a UIViewRepresentable to place it in your SwiftUI code. You may know that already, so if you truly want *pure* SwiftUI, you may be out of luck here. Hopefully more TextField features are migrated to SwiftUI soon.