# textField delegates are not being called

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Below mentioned are my textField delegate methods, I am using IQKeyBoardSwift for inteligent keyboard.
I tried removing my keyboard but still I am not receiving call on any of my method accept 'begins touch'

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == textField {
        textFIeld2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == textFIeld2 {
        textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == textField3 {
        textFIeld4.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == textFIeld4 {
        textFIeld4.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}

// Resign first reponder on touch
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let location = touch.location(in: view)

    if !textField1.frame.contains(location) {
        textField1.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if !textFIeld2.frame.contains(location) {
        textFIeld2.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if !textField3.frame.contains(location) {
        textField3.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if !textFIeld4.frame.contains(location) {
        textFIeld4.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    self.textField1.endEditing(true)
    self.textFIeld2.endEditing(true)
    self.textField3.endEditing(true)
    self.textFIeld4.endEditing(true)
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("textFieldShouldBeginEditing")
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("textFieldDidBeginEditing")
    print("Leaving textFieldDidBeginEditing")
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if(textField == textField1)
    {
        if(newString.characters.count) == 1 {
            print(textField1)
            textFIeld2.becomeFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

    }

    if(textField == textFIeld2)
    {
        if(newString.characters.count) == 1{
            textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
    }
    if(textField == textField3)
    {
        if(newString.characters.count) == 1{
            textFIeld4.becomeFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
    }

    if(textField == textFIeld4)
    {
        if(newString.characters.count) == 1{
            buttonOutletSubmitCode.isHidden = false
            resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I want my cursor to jump to next textfield after receiving an input of 1 character. Unfortunately That is not happening.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField1.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
        textFIeld2.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
        textField3.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
        textFIeld4.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    }
```

This is my viewDidLoad

Comment: all the IBOutlets are connected

Comment: textFieldShouldBeginEditing is this method called ?

Comment: No, it's not called. I want to restrict user from entering more than one character in textfield

Comment: any delegate method called ?

Comment: Begins touch only

Comment: @RajatAttri replace you code.

Comment: add protocol UITextFieldDelegate and try to replace      textField1?.delegate = self as UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: for check for juum to nextfield : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18711677/3901620

Comment: @RajatAttri check this for length : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1773257/3901620

Comment: @RajatAttri first you need to set your view controller as the text field delegate `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {`

Comment: next set the viewController as the textField delegate in the method viewDidLoad `textField1.delegate = self` `textFIeld2.delegate = self` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding :**

Add protocol `UITextFieldDelegate` and try to replace `textField1?.delegate = self as UITextFieldDelegate`

**Replace**

This **doesn't** work:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
}
```

**This works**:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_textField: UITextField) {
}
```

**For jump textField**

see :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18711677/3901620

Comment: did you check in simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding textFiled delegate :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  , UITextFieldDelegate{
```

Yes, Its Not Call because of your delegate is OLD swift version. Replace it Swift 3 code.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
  if textField == textField {
        textFIeld2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == textFIeld2 {
        textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == textField3 {
        textFIeld4.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == textFIeld4 {
        textFIeld4.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: @RajatAttri textField connection with delegate in storyboard.